# shutdown is automatically interrupted once

Tags: xubuntu, shutdown

For about 2 weeks now (I have no idea what triggered the change though) my Xubuntu 16.04 system doesn't do anything when i press the shutdown button (via the `whisker menu->logout->shutdown`), except for closing my Seafile main window. All other windows and applications (including the Seafile in the tray) continue to function like normal. Only after pressing shutdown again does the system proceed with a regular shutdown.

I assume no-one knows what causes this strange behaviour or how to fix it. How can I debug this? I don't see anything suspicious in the syslog nor dmesg.

UPDATE: now when I try to log out a second time, it fails as well but now a message

> Received error while trying to log out: Session manager must be in idle state when requesting a shutdown

Comment: Does your machine stop if you run `sudo shutdown -h now`?

Comment: yes, in fact in does :)
Possibly related: https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/issues/15474
with fix: https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/pull/16227
But I haven't tried the fix yet since I don't know anything about Nix

Comment: The fix I posted is from 2016, so I assume it should already have been implemented. I'm also using the xenial-backports PPA so I guess that related issue isn't the real problem after all.